# Как можно обрезать строку?

Tags: c#, строки

Допустим есть строка в listBox "UserFIrstName UserLastName 21993842". Как обрезать эту строку, чтобы осталось "UserFIrstName" или "UserFIrstName UserLastName"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте [метод `Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string s = "UserFIrstName UserLastName 21993842";
string[] parts = s.Split(' '); // или s.Split() - роль разделителей будут играть любые пробельные символы
Console.WriteLine(parts[0]);
```

Comment: а почему не просто Split() ?

Comment: Да почему-то засомневался когда в MSDN не увидел метода без параметров, а студию лень запускать было, но сейчас вижу, что [эта перегрузка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) принимает `params`, который, конечно, может содержать 0 элементов :)

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам известны с какого символа начинается и размер того куска, который вы выделяете, можно использовать

```
string s = "<your string>";
string result = s.Substring(0,13); //result UserFirstName
```

Если неизвестно, то можно использовать разделение строки по регулярному выражению. В вашем случае это:

```
string s = "UserFIrstName UserLastName 21993842";
string[] parts = s.Split(' '); //part[0] = UserFirstName, part[1] = UserLastName and e.g.
```

Comment: Где тут у вас регулярное выражение?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, знак пробела является таким же регулярным выражением как и любое другое. Если Вам будет удобнее, можете называть это разделителем.

Comment: Даже если так, `string.Split()` не работает с регулярками, он просто сравнивает символы

Comment: Уже не помню, спасибо за помощь!